# How to click element in Puppeteer using xPath

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, puppeteer

I want to click on an element without using css selectors.

```
await page.click()
```

uses selectors to identify the element.

---

So how can I do something like this?

```
await page.click('/*[@id="toc"]/ul/li[1]/a')
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

First I had to get the element by using

```
await page.$x('<xPath>')
```

It returns an array with elements. To click I had to choose the first element in the array.

```
const elements = await page.$x('<xPath>')
await elements[0].click()
```

Comment: Hi , by using the above code, getting "Type Error: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined." Can you please help me in fixing the issue.

Comment: @Explorer Probably your xPath does not select elements.

Comment: When I hit that type error - I was truing to do the selector and immediately access the element:
`await page.$x('<xPath')[0].click()` - when I broke it down into two awaits, the error disappears. @Explorer - are you following the code example?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `xpath` prefix with puppeteer 19 and newer

```js
await page.click('xpath/' + xpathExpression)
```

e.g.

```js
await page.click('xpath//*[@id="toc"]/ul/li[1]/a')
```

Comment: This works great for me, thank you. I'm just adding a comment to link to documentation of this feature at https://pptr.dev/guides/query-selectors#xpath-selectors-xpath, since it was not documented where I expected it to be, at https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.click.

Answer (score 1):

```
const click = await page.waitForXPath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a[2]')
 click.click();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.