# How do I select a button having only type and value attributes?

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, puppeteer

I've been using Puppeteer for about a month now but I can't for the life of me figure out how to click on this button:

```
<input type="button" value="Dismiss this error">
```

It has a dynamic selector that changes every time the page is opened so I can't use waitForSelector.

What I've tried so far is `await page.click("input[value='Dismiss this error']");` and `await page.click(coordinates of button);` but neither of these have worked.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58087966/puppeteer-how-to-click-element-using-xpath

Answer (score 0):

Try using the xpath.

```
let button = await page.$x('elementXpath');
button = button[0];
await page.evaluate(x => x.click(), button);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the button using the

```
const button = await page.waitForSelector('input[value="Dismiss this error"]');
```

or

```
const button = await page.waitForSelector('input[type="button"]');
```

and then just call

```
await button.click();
```

What I would recommend is to pay attention to the parent tags, maybe they have some unique identifiers and you can stick to them, like

```
const button = await page.waitForSelector('#parentId input');
```

in this case, you will get a more reliable selector. Also, if you can't click on the button it's maybe not because you didn't find it properly but because it's overlapped/hidden by some other element and you shouldn't click on on `input` directly but on the parent of this input.