# Targeting auto-generated elements with node.js puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am using puppeteer for node.js v13.3.1, I am building a bot that will apply to jobs on linkedIn.
So far I have the following code.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
   const SEARCHPARAM = "react" // change this for search param 
require("dotenv").config();
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.linkedin.com/login?fromSignIn=true&trk=guest_homepage-basic_nav-header-signin')
  await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 1080});
  await page.type("#username", process.env.NAMEUSERNAME)
  await page.type("#password", process.env.PASSWORD)
  await page.click('button[type="submit"]')
  //works fine
  await Promise.all([
    await page.waitForNavigation(), 
    await page.click('#global-nav > div > nav > ul > li:nth-child(3)'), 
    await page.type('input', SEARCHPARAM ), 
    await page.click('button[type="button"]'),
    await page.click('#ember1052 > span') //Will not hit the button
  ]);


})();
```

So far the bot is logging in and searching with the `SEARCHPARAM` just fine, however  I am having trouble getting the bot to hit the `easy apply` button on the job posting. Whenever I target this button I get the id as `ember`(number) and this number is never the same on different browser windows. I have tried targeting the button by class but node is telling me that it cannot find that selector.

Puppeteer docs for reference [docs](https://pptr.dev/)

Answer (score 0):

Please see this link for more detailed answer:
 [How to click element in Puppeteer using xPath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58087966/ddg#58088028)

```
const elements = await page.$x('<xPath>')
await elements[0].click()
```

And your XPath selector should be like this:

```
const element = await page.$x('//button/span[text()="Easy Apply"]')
```

Code syntax for:
`Button element that contain span element which has text inside "Easy Apply"`

Comment: I'm also stupid, but please select this as right answer if it helps. Thanks